# Change language (country) in lstlisting

Tags: listings

I'm using `lstlisting` to insert a code in my text. Fine. But I'm writing in PT_BR and want to change the word "Listing" to "Listagem" in my list (list caption from english to portuguese) so my code listing will become

```
Listagem 1. Texto em português
```

instead

```
Listing 1. Texto em português
```

Now using:

```
\usepackage{sbc-template}  
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
  frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
```

and the code in the text:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={Texto em português},label=mylabel]

#some code

\end{lstlisting}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See section 5.7 of [the listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf): the `\lstlistingname` macro, in particular.

Comment: Nice! Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I can, but the question has been answered several times before (didn't check for duplicates before I commented). Will move to close this question as a result.

Comment: Agree. Sorry for this.